# Quantum master equation for light in medium with dissipation

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-optics, effective-field-theory

The effective theory of photons in medium is usually obtained by inserting the electric susceptibility $\chi$ (linear or nonlinear) into $\int \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{D}} \cdot \mathbf{E}$ and complete the integral. We can calculate $\chi$ by introducing $H_{\text{dipole}} = - \mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{E}$ as a perturbation to the electron part of the system, where $\mathbf{E}$ is treated as a given external field, and then calculating $\mathbf{d}$. This is equivalent to "integrating out" the electron degrees of freedom and getting an effective Hamiltonian of photons.

In real materials, dissipation (by phonon scattering or spontaneous emssion) always exists, and the behavior of the electrons has to be treated by a quantum master equation, instead of a zero-temperature formalism; now $\chi$, defined as the response of $\mathbf{d}$ to $\mathbf{E}$, no longer captures how the state of photons evolve in the material: if we inject a coherent state (a pure state by definition) into the material, the output will be a mixed state, but this piece of information can't be captured by $\chi$. I'm therefore curious about whether in this case, it's still possible to write down an effective theory for photons in the medium - possibly a quantum master equation as well?

This question may have some practical values since if you are to do a quantum optics experiment, it might be instructive to know what the lenses really do to the optical field; but I'm not an experimentalist and what I heard from experimentalist is "well you just need to lower the temperature to avoid anything weird".

Comment: Wouldn't such dissipation just contribute to the loss of photons from the state? In that case, the coherent states would remain pure.

Comment: Not necessarily right? Suppose you inject a Fock state |N> into the lens; now the probability for it to become |N-1> is p_1, and the probability for it to become |N-2> is p_2, and all p_n are non-zero, so the output state is \sum_n p_n |N-n><N-n| - a mixed state.

Comment: That is the difference between Fock states and coherent states. A loss causes a Fock state to become mixed, but a coherent state remains pure if it suffers a loss.